# How to convert dataframe date into yyyy-mm--dd format in csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

Having date and blank string value in dataframe while converting it its coming in `dd/mm/yyyy` format to csv file but needed `yyyy-mm-dd` format

Consider this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Name":["James", "Alice", "Phil", "Jacob"],"DOB": ["07-01-1997", "06-02-1995", "", "03-07-2002"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You can do so in 2 steps:

```
# Convert the DOB to datetime
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])

# Convert datetime to your intended string format
df['DOB'] = df['DOB'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

which gives you:

```
    Name         DOB
0  James  1997-07-01
1  Alice  1995-06-02
2   Phil         NaN
3  Jacob  2002-03-07
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I used this one but while sending it to csv its changing. In csv am getting 7/1/1997 this format.
.

Comment: Am getting below output : But in csv file its changing:Name DOB
0 James 1997-07-01
1 Alice 1995-06-02
2 Phil NaT
3 Jacob 2002-03-07

Comment: What do you use to read the saved csv? If you are using `Excel` to open your csv file, it automatically reads `dates` and convert them to `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` according to your setting. Try opening the csv using notepad editor, you will see that it is in the correct format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: if this answers your question, you can consider accepting it.